# Can outlook read an email an export certain data to an excel sheet?

Tags: vba, email, excel

Ok. I edited the question to see if you can see where I'm making a mistake.
This is the email. It will come in ALWAYS with this structure except, after Job1. there could be six more lines. But I'll deal with that later.
here is the email:

*email subject: "Report Of Property"*    (not part of email body. Line 1 is Name:. There are NO empty lines between paragraphs.)

Name: **geo.**

Time started: 03:10PM **10-Aug-2014**

Time ended: 03:11PM 10-Aug-2014

Property: **48 Atlantic Close**

Complete Checklist: **No**

Call out: **Yes**

Sage nº: **16**

Jobs done:

Job1.**worked1** *after this paragraghs there could be more(job2,job3,etc.) but I'll deal with that                    later*

*Item: . Price: 0£. Stock:0£.

*Item: . Price: 0£. Stock:0£.

*Item: . Price: 0£. Stock:0£.

*Item: . Price: 0£. Stock:0£.

*Item: . Price: 0£. Stock:0£.

*Item: . Price: 0£. Stock:0£.

All the **bold** fields are the ones I need to import to an excel file.

Date to column A, name to column B, sage to column D , complete checklist to column F and jobs done to column G. 
this is the VBA code you gave me and I tried to edit it like this:

```
       Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
      'Excel objects
      Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
      Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
      Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet


      Dim id As Variant  'used to iterate the EntryIDCollection
      Dim email As Outlook.MailItem  'represents each email item
      Dim msgText As Variant 'Array used to iterate the "lines" in the email:

      'Create an instance of Excel that we can use:
      Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")


      For Each id In Split(EntryIDCollection, ",")
      'Assign a mailItem variable to this email:
      Set email = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(id)

     'Add some logic to ensure you only process the right emails.
     ' you could use a defined subject and/or sender name, etc.
     ' MODIFY AS NEEDED
     If email.Subject = "Report of Property" Then

         'Ignore the HTML format, just use the "Body". Parsing HTML can be a pain
         ' in the a$$ and it is *probably* not needed here since you control the
         ' format of the email anyways.

         'This example simply prints the entire email contents in an Excel sheet
         'Add a new workbook
         Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
         Set xlSheet = xlWB.Worksheets(1)

         Dim line As Variant
         For Each line In Split(email.Body, vbCrLf)
              If Left(line, 1) = "Name:" Then
                  xlSheet.Range("B6").Value = Trim(Mid(line, 6))
              ElseIf Left(line, 2) = "Time started:" Then
                  xlSheet.Range("A6").Value = DateValue(Trim(Mid(line, 14)))
              ElseIf Left(line, 7) = "Sage Nº:" Then
                  xlSheet.Range("D6").Value = Trim(Mid(line, 6))
              ElseIf Left(line, 5) = "Complete Checklist:" Then
                  xlSheet.Range("F6").Value = Trim(Mid(line, 6))
              ElseIf Left(line, 5) = "Job1" Then
                  xlSheet.Range("G6").Value = Trim(Mid(line, 6))

              End If
         Next


     Else

     End If
 Next
 End Sub
```

Comment: Here is some info below; I'm not answering the *specifics* -- I suspect that with some trial & error, and googling, you will be able to get the specifics taken care of, and that you just need a hint in the right direction to get started.
Hopefully this will help show you some of the objects/methods that you can use to process email and put info from that email in to Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Outlook can process incoming emails and then you can use that data to do just about anything that VBA is capable of doing, such as putting the data in an Excel spreadsheet, writing out to a plain text file, etc. etc.

You can use the Application-level event procedure for `NewMail`, which is raised any time a new *email* item is received (I believe this ignores other item types such as calendar appointments, tasks, etc., for which you can use the `NewMailEx` event which processes all incoming items).

The `NewMailEx` event receives a comma-delimted string of Unique IDs associated with each mail item.  Use simple `Split` function to convert that to an iterable array.

Then bind Excel to Outlook, create a new spreadsheet, and input whatever information you need. This example uses early-binding which will require a reference to the Excel library.

```
Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
'Excel objects
Dim xlApp as Excel.Application
Dim xlWB as Excel.Workbook
Dim xlSheet as Excel.Worksheet

MsgBox "Mail received!" '## DELETE THIS LINE ONCE YOU VERIFY THAT THE MACRO RUNS 

Dim id as Variant  'used to iterate the EntryIDCollection
Dim email as Outlook.MailItem  'represents each email item 
Dim msgText as Variant 'Array used to iterate the "lines" in the email:

'Create an instance of Excel that we can use:
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")


For each id in Split(EntryIDCollection, ",")
    'Assign a mailItem variable to this email:   
    Set email = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(id)

    'Add some logic to ensure you only process the right emails.  
    ' you could use a defined subject and/or sender name, etc.
    ' MODIFY AS NEEDED
    If email.Subject = "PROCESS THIS EMAIL" Then 

        'Ignore the HTML format, just use the "Body". Parsing HTML can be a pain
        ' in the a$$ and it is *probably* not needed here since you control the 
        ' format of the email anyways.

        'This example simply prints the entire email contents in an Excel sheet
        'Add a new workbook
        Set xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
        Set xlSheet = xlWB.Worksheets(1)

        'Put the email contents in the worksheet:
        xlSheet.Range("A1").Value = email.Body

        'Or you could do something like this, MODIFY AS NEEDED:
        'dim line as Variant
        'For each line in Split(email.Body, vbCrLf)
        '     If Left(line, 5) = "Name:" Then
        '         xlSheet.Range("B1").Value = Trim(Mid(line, 6))
        '     ElseIf Left(line, 13) = "Time started:" Then
        '         xlSheet.Range("C1").Value = DateValue(Trim(Mid(line, 14)))
        '     EndIf 
        'Next


    Else:
         ' do nothing for emails that don't need to be processed
    End If

    xlApp.Visible = True

Next
End Sub
```

Realistically, pulling all this various info from an email there are many different ways that it *could* be done, I show you a simple example above, some more reliable (and more complicated than others).

- Do you want to use Regular Expressions?
- Or can you get by using simple string functions like `Left`, `Mid`,
  etc.
- Outlook also supports using a WordEditor and Word's rich text object model to parse by paragraph, etc...

Specific implementations of any of these or other methods seems outside scope of this question, which I gather is:  **"how to export text from an Outlook email to an Excel   spreadhseet?**

This should be enough to get you started I hope :)

If you have specific trouble implementing it, parsing the needed information, etc., I would encourage you to ask additional (new) questions but not before browsing the Outlook Object Model Reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff870566(v=office.14).aspx

And the similar reference for Excel:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff846392(v=office.14).aspx

**NOTE** This code provided is *not tested* and may contain some typos, misplaced parentheses. I encourage you to always declare variables and use `Option Explicit` to force variable declaration in your modules.

**NOTE** This example will create a new file for each email, probably not desired. In order to tap an existing file, you need to know it's location and be able to open it. Instead of `Set xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add`, do `Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("c:\path\to\file.xlsx").  Using an existing file creates a host of additional "problems" for someone who isn't versed in VBA, such as "how do I find the next empty row in a worksheet" (Asked & answered here dozens of times), etc.

So I would start with this, and obviously if you cannot "get it", when you get stuck, break it down in to small chunks or steps in the process.  Try and figure out how to do each step, before trying to put them all together.

Good luck!

(I should have better things to do on a Saturday night, but I have a 2-year old and the wife's out of town...)

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. It is very complete. I will give it a try. Yes the references are are always different. but always of the same type(date, name, sage and isuues.) They are always preceeded by the same text though. I'll try it now. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again. I just can't get around this cause I really don't know what I'm doing. I pasted the code into outlooks VBA and pressed f5 to test. But a window came up asking me for macros(?). I have never worked with VBA and although I can see some "methods" in the code I don't know what the hell I'm doing. Is there a way I could learn the basics of VBA?

Comment: You will need to paste it in the module called `ThisOutlookSession` I think.  Make sure its there and not somewhere else.  If you get errors or pop ups I would neef to know the full message.  This macro cannot be tested by F5 because it is an event procedure. You can test it by sending yourself an email.

Comment: Thanks. I finnaly got an understanding. I'm just stuck at the last if statement. I put in: email.Subject <> "Report " Then but i don't know what else to add. Thank you.

Comment: learn the basics... well you are an app developer, no? So I assume you have some basic understanding of object-oriented programming.  "Learning" the basics is more about familiarizing oneself with the object model. I have included links to both object model references used in this example.  I'm afraid that any sort of "intro to VBA" that you might find would likely be very focused on *Excel* only (most people only know VBA from Excel, even though it is cross-application).

Comment: Why would you use the `<>` operator?  The `If` block evaluates messages that match the criteria (i.e., messages that you want to process).  If the messages have a subject `"REPORT"`, then you should use an `=` operator.

Comment: [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj692812(v=office.15).aspx) is also a fairly comprehensive list of generic VBA statements (not application/object-model specific; these statements control the flow of code etc., like Loops, I/O statements, etc.)

Comment: Thank you David. I didn't use the<>. I seem to have the code ok now, but nothing happens when I receive a message.

Comment: hehehe app developer... Not yet. I've just made one so far, and, although it works, I don't consider myself to be a developer yet. hehehe

Comment: OK, I added a `MsgBox` prompt at the beginning, this will pop up every time you receive an email. Use this to verify that the event is working, and delete that line once you no longer need it.  I also added a line towards the end to make Excel *visible*. I forgot that previously.

Comment: Hi David. I edited the question so that you could have a better view of what i'm doing. By the way.The macro is running. So I must have made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: OK I see two things... **1** Your `Left` functions aren't right.  `Left(Line, _n_)` returns the left `_n_` characters of that line.  It looks like you were using it as though it returns a specific line number.  So, for "Time started:" you will need to do `Left(line, 13)` as in my example, etc.

Comment: **2**: related to #1, you will need to need to adjust the `Mid` functions, so if you do `If Left(line, 13)...` then it should be like `Trim(Mid(line, 14))..` etc.  The `Mid` function used this way will return the remainder of the line, *starting* from the specified character index. SO if the left 13 characters = "Time started:" then we want to return the *rest of that line* but omitting "Time started:".

Comment: The VBA is running but my excel sheet is popping up empty. I'm sorry for being a nuisance... I edited like you said. But it still comes out empty. Even with the mistakes shouldn't I be getting some data in?

Comment: I also added a MsgBox  to the last else statement to make sure that it was gathering the data. That MsgBox isn't showing up. So I'm guessing that the problem is in writting to excel.

Comment: I'm actually surprised it didn't cause an error. You need to do `xlSheet.Range(...` FYI you can put a `MsgBox` just about anywhere and use that to help debug, for example if you put `Msgbox line` inside the `For each line...` loop, it will show you the line text.

Comment: I actually had tried that. Aside from the xlSheet. did you make any other changes? I've allowed all macros on both Outlook and excel with no luck. If I try to send the whole body it gets the data and outs it in cell a1. But with the trimed results I get no data at all. I'm going to set msgboxes lie you sadi and give it a go to see where im going wrong

Comment: Also you can use *breakpoints* to pause the exeuction of the code, and then step through it line-by-line using the F8 key.  Here are some tips for debugging: www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx

Comment: As I thought, it's jumping the if statement. that means that it's not finding the parameters, right? Could you just confirm, please, Left(line, 1) refers to the Left of line 1 right?

Comment: One problem might be with the `Split` function. I'm assuming that lines are separated by a `vbCrLf` which is pretty standard, it's a "carriage return/line feed". But you could try `Split(email.Body, vbCr)` or `Split(email.Body, vbLf)` instead maybe?

Comment: **NO**. Like I mentioned in the comment on the original post, `Left(line, 1)` returns the Left *one* character from each line.  In my example, I did like `Left(line, 5) = "Name:"` because `"Name:"` is 5 characters long :)

Comment: so you need to fix your `Left` and `Mid` functions. I would start with those first, and then if it's still not working, debug the `Split` function.

Comment: I got Name! but no other ones. I'll check again

Comment: ahhhhh. Ok. Got it. So it searches all the lines for that parameter? Ok. Will do. Thank you for being so helpfull.

Comment: OK, if you're getting the name correctly, then I think you just need to tweak the `Left` and `Mid` :)

Comment: Yep the `For each line` iterates each "line" in the email. Then we test the `Left(line, _n_)` for various values and write to the Excel depending on what that line contains.

Comment: Trying now. they are finnaly starting to show. as you said i had to get my left and mid functions. I'm starting to get a hang of them. Left(line, 8) = "Sage Nº:" Isn't this 8?

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much. You have been very helpful. I couldn't have done this without you! Now just have to figure out how to make it open a specific `file` and add to the `next line`. THANK YOU!!!